# How to combine create and edit page in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I am new for the react and react-admin, but I am now using it in our project, everything is good, but there is one thing I don't know how to make it. in our application. the create and edit page almost same, the only difference is some fields are disabled in edit view, so I want to combine create and edit, is there any document about it. I searched it but it seems not an easy way to do it, it's appreciated if can get some sample code. thank you !!!

Hi @Mads, thank you for your answer, I update the question here.  what I mean is last time, i also create a separate form like what you did and I insert the component directly as below (e.g. **`<Form/>`**). it will get an error: **the invalid value for prop ‘save’ on  tag**
I am just curious what's the difference with this way (**`{form('edit')}`**)

`<Edit {...props} undoable={false} style={{width: '100%'}}> <Form/> </Edit>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
const form = type => (
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="name"/>
        {type === 'create' ? <TextInput source="created_at"/> : ''}
    </SimpleForm>
);

export const EditView = ({classes, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <Edit {...props} undoable={false} style={{width: '100%'}}>
            {form('edit')}
        </Edit>
    );
};

export const CreateView = ({classes, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <Edit {...props} undoable={false} style={{width: '100%'}}>
            {form('create')}
        </Edit>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi @Mads, thank you for your answer,  it's working, can i ask you one more question, I code as below:
    <Edit {...props} undoable={false} style={{width: '100%'}}>
            **<Form/>**
 </Edit>
 the functionality is ok but gets one warning:  **the invalid value for prop ‘save’ on <div> tag.**     is there any difference with your method {form('edit')}

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking... Can you format the code in the answer for better readability?

Comment: Now I can see what you mean :-) I am not an expert in React, so the explanation may be faulty, but: My example calls a function, which returns a component ( <SimpleForm /> ) where your example tries to use it directly as a React component.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar struggle and this is what I ended up doing:

```js
// This is the reusable form component
const CategoryForm = (props) => (
  <SimpleForm {...props}>
    <TextInput source="name" label="Nome" />
    {props.type === "edit" && <p>This element only shows in edit mode</p>}
  </SimpleForm>
);

// Edit View Component
export const CategoryEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    {/* Reusable form component with type prop set to 'edit' */}
    <CategoryForm type="edit" />
  </Edit>
);

// Create View Component
export const CategoryCreate = (props) => (
  <Create {...props}>
    {/* Reusable form component with type prop set to 'create' */}
    <CategoryForm type="create" />
  </Create>
);
```

Comment: so spooky that I've had this exact same problem for about an hour, which is apparently about the same time as you posted this answer, as if ready for me to find as a solution.  thank you :)